# Why doesn't default Eclipse complain about unused method parameters?

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to know why Eclipse doesn't by default register an error or warning about a method like this:

```
public void setX(int x) {
    // empty method body
}
```

You can turn a warning on for this that reads "The parameter x is never read", in Preferences>Java>Compiler>Errors/Warnings>Unnecessary Code.  You can set this warning so that it ignores overriding and implementing methods.

I can only think of one reason why you may want to ignore the situation in the code I pasted: you may want to call a particular version of an overloaded method by using an arbitrary-value argument of a particular type.  It seems that would be very bad programming practice though.  Is there some better reason for leaving this warning off by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One situation where it can be useful is if you're writing deliberate no-op methods in a base class, which can be overridden by derived classes. Think of things like [`MouseAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) for example.

The problem is there's no way of indicating *in the language* "yes, this is deliberately a no-op"... the compiler either has to take comments into account, or you've got to use `@SuppressWarnings` etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Link to filters settings](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cprbview.htm)

In the filters, you can set it to "On selected element only", and then you get rid of alot of warnings. I use that setting, and it's very helpful.

Comment: *enter link description here*?